# Как перемещать текст в AvalonEdit как в VisualStudio

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

Прошу помочь в написании функции для **AvalonEdit**

по перемещению (вверх или вниз) текста (выделенного или без выделения)

на подобие того как это реализовано в **VisualStudio**

с использованием горячих клавиш - Alt + Стрелка.Вниз или Стрелка.Вверх

Особенности реализации

- Если текст выделен - перемещать текст с сохранением выделения
- Если нет выделенного участка текста - перемещать текущую строку
- Ограничение перемещения текста по границам текста в AvalonEdit

Comment: Хорошее ТЗ, вот только по ТЗ здесь не ничего не пишут за вас. Здесь вы сами пишете код, и если у вас что-то конкретное не получается - мы поможем. Если вам нужна помощь в написании кода по ТЗ, идите на фриланс-биржу или наймите разработчика.

Comment: Могу посоветовать следующее: в обработчике нажатия указанных комбинаций клавиш вырезаете в классе [TextDocument](http://avalonedit.net/documentation/html/5a2ba854-ebff-07db-c34a-3d7f65f5ca76.htm) кусок текста методом Remove и вставляете выше/ниже методом Insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо **Alexander Petrov**

Часть кода Взято из исходников AvalonEdit https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit

Описание встроенных команд в AvalonEdit - Команда DeleteLine            https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/blob/106b31efe17a4992e1c02ee5c8650bc86591aeb7/ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit/Editing/EditingCommandHandler.cs#L499

```csharp
        // Перемещение текста на одну строчку вверх
        static void MoveTextToLineUp(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextEditor textEditor = target as TextEditor;
            TextArea textArea = (target as TextEditor)?.TextArea;// as TextArea;

            // Если объект нулевой вернуться
            if (textArea == null || textArea.Document == null)
                return;

            // индексы первой и последней строчки исходного выделенного текста
            int firstLineIndex, lastLineIndex;
            
            // Проверяем выделенный исходный текст
            if (textArea.Selection.Length == 0)
            {
                // Если ни чего не выделено, индексы указывают на одну и ту же строчку
                firstLineIndex = lastLineIndex = textArea.Caret.Line;
            }
            else
            {
                // Если выделен фрагмент текста, ищем начальную и конечную строчки
                firstLineIndex = Math.Min(textArea.Selection.StartPosition.Line, textArea.Selection.EndPosition.Line);
                lastLineIndex = Math.Max(textArea.Selection.StartPosition.Line, textArea.Selection.EndPosition.Line);
            }

            // Если выбрана первая строка - то и двигать уже не нужно - возвращаемся
            if (firstLineIndex < 2) return;
            
            //Номер предыдущей за исходными текстом
            int prevlineNumber = firstLineIndex - 1;

            DocumentLine PrevLine = textArea.Document.GetLineByNumber(prevlineNumber);
            
            // Последняя строка исходного текста
            DocumentLine endLine = textArea.Document.GetLineByNumber(lastLineIndex);

            // Текст в предыдущей строчке перед выделенным текстом
            string PrevText = textArea.Document.Text.Substring(PrevLine.Offset, PrevLine.TotalLength);

            // Сначала вставляем за исходным текстом
            textArea.Document.Insert(endLine.Offset + endLine.TotalLength, PrevText);
            //Затем удаляем предыдущую строчку
            textArea.Document.Remove(PrevLine.Offset, PrevLine.TotalLength);
           
            //Передаем управление обратно
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```